# Chromedriver cannot retrieve the element when .add_argument("--headless")?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I would like to use selenium chromedriver to fill up the login & pw in https://www.asiamiles.com/en/login.html, however, I found that the .find_elemen_by_xpath only works if I dont set the .add_argument to "--headless"

I am guessing the input got hidden if I run the chromedriver in the background...

```
asia_miles_url = 'https://www.asiamiles.com/en/login.html'
driver         = ws_functions.get_ChromeDriver(()) #it works
# driver         = ws_functions.get_ChromeDriver(("--headless")) #it doesn't work
driver.implicitly_wait(30)
driver.get(asia_miles_url)
time.sleep(8)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div/input').send_keys('abc')
time.sleep(1)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div/input').send_keys(password)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[3]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/div/form/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/div[3]/button').click()
```

My custom functions in **ws_functions**:

```
#Get ChromeDriver
def get_ChromeDriver(*headless): #turple headless = null -> Chrome runs in foregound
chrome_options  = Options()
if headless[0] == "--headless":
    chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_options.add_argument("window-size=1920,1080")
return webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=settings.chromedriver,options=chrome_options)
```

Does anyone know why? Thanks.

Comment: Before `send_keys()`, get and print the HTML page source, then check page source to make sure if the element `input` is available.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the arguments like this

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()

chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
# chrome_options.headless = True # also works
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome_options)

start_url = "<Your URL>"
driver.get(start_url)
```

Comment: My question is that I have added the upon code you have mentioned, but seems the chromedriver only works without the '--headless'.

Answer (score 0):

First off here's a simple xpath you can use. The next issue is when running headless the site might pick up that your a bot.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
driver.get('https://www.asiamiles.com/en/login.html')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='username'])[2]"))).send_keys('abc')
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//input[@id='password'])[2]"))).send_keys(password)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"(//button[.='Log in'])[3]"))).click()
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

If you print driver.page_source

```
<html><head>
<title>Access Denied</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Access Denied</h1>
 
You don't have permission to access "http://www.asiamiles.com/en/login.html" on this server.<p>
Reference #18.869a3b17.1614165148.2921fb4b


</p></body></html>
```

Comment: So which means that if the website would know that I’m a bot, then I would not able to use —headless ?

Comment: You can try and figure out why it's like this by checking out user agents, changing your selenium files, chromedriver options and many others.